# AppleScript, which calls Disk Utility to make DMG file

Tags: macos, applescript

How can I make Apple-script file, which calls Disk Utility (usual OS X app) and makes it create DMG file from fixed folder (e.g. folder "../dir/dir2").

Is it possible to do this, using Apple-script?
I use OS X 10.8 here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it without opening Disk Utility.app

```
set sourceFolder to "/Users/myuser/path/to/folder/"
set dmgPath to choose file name
do shell script "/usr/bin/hdiutil create " & quoted form of POSIX path of dmgPath & " -ov -srcfolder " & quoted form of sourceFolder
```

You will prompted to provide a destination file

Comment: I think it should be `choose file of type...` rather than `choose file name of type ...`

Comment: @MarkSetchell No actually it's without `of type`.

Comment: Ok, thank you for checking and updating - I am trying to learn too :-)